# Possible to tag metadata to an arbitrary file in Linux?

Tags: linux, debian, files, filesystems

I am on an x86_64 Debian machine using a cifs file system. I was wondering if it's possible to add arbitrary metadata to a file. The restrictions would be:

- It would 'stick' if the file is renamed.
- It cannot alter the content of the file (md5 has to stay the same)

For example, let's say I wanted to add the metadata of "hi" to the file at /tmp/myfile.mov. Is it possible to do that? Unfortunately, due to some constraints, using a database won't work (the filenames, paths, can change...there are no constraints) and modifying the name itself is not possible (as that name can be further modified).

So, back to my question: is it possible to tag metadata to a file in Linux? There is something similar to this on Mac, where you can do this via the Finder window via "comments" or "tags":

[image]

(Perhaps related to: https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/xattr.7.html. But it seems that's not on my system.)